# Indexing a pandas dataframe with datetime.date index leads to KeyError

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date

I retrieve some data from my MySQL database. This data has the date (not datetime) in one column and some other random data in the other columns. Let's say `dtf` is my dataframe. There is no index yet so I set one

```py
dtf.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

Now I would like to get data from a specific date, so I write for example:

```py
dtf.loc['2000-01-03']
```

or just

```py
dtf['2000-01-03']
```

This gives me a `KeyError`:

```
KeyError: '2000-01-03'
```

But I know it's in there; `dtf.head()` shows me that.
So I took a look at the type of the index of the first row:

```py
type(dtf.index[0])
```

and it tells me: `datetime.date`. All good. Now if I just type

```py
dtf.index
```

the output is

```
Index([2000-01-03, 2000-01-04, 2000-01-05, 2000-01-06, 2000-01-07, 2000-01-10,
       2000-01-11, 2000-01-12, 2000-01-13, 2000-01-14,
       ...
       2015-09-09, 2015-09-10, 2015-09-11, 2015-09-14, 2015-09-15, 2015-09-16,
       2015-09-17, 2015-09-18, 2015-09-21, 2015-09-22],
       dtype='object', name='date', length=2763)
```

I am a bit confused about the `dtype='object'`. Shouldn't this read `datetime.date`?

If I use `datetime` in my mysql table instead of `date` everything works like a charm. Is this a bug or a feature? I really would like to use `datetime.date` because it describes my data best.

My pandas version is 0.17.0
I am using python 3.5.0
My os is arch linux

Answer (score 6):

You should use datetime64/Timestamp rather than datetime.datetime:

```
dtf.index = pd.to_datetime(dtf.index)
```

will mean you have a DatetimeIndex and can do nifty things like loc by strings.

```
dtf.loc['2000-01-03']
```

*You won't be able to do that with datetime.datetime.*

Comment: Also, note numpy only has special support for a few dtypes, not one for every type of object. Generally these are ones where it's more efficient to pack them as a C-array of that data type, rather than with object dtype where it's a C-array of pointers to python objects (which will always be slower).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using datetime.datetime works perfectly well and I can do the query you tell me I can not. Furthermore I do not have a problem with datetime.datetime, but with datetime.DATE. I tried your solution but it did not change anything. I get the same KeyError :( Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you convert `df.index` into dtype `datetime64` using `pd.to_datetime`, the type of each index, in fact, becomes type `datetime.datetime`. You can verify:

```py
import datetime
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5)}, index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2000-01-05', 5).date) 

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
isinstance(df.index[0], datetime.datetime)       # True
```

As [Andy Hayden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33268134/19123103) mentioned, once you convert the index into `datetime64`, you can do the sort of indexing OP wants, such as

```py
df.loc['2000-01-03']
# or for range of dates
df.loc['2000-01-03':'2000-01-05']
```

Besides, null times don't render even if the dtype is `datetime64`, so visually, it's exactly the same.

That said, if you want to use `datetime.date`, you can still do so by explicitly using `datetime.date`. For example, to select values on `2000-01-03`, you can use either `loc` or `query`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5)}, index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2000-01-05', 5).date) 

df.loc[datetime.date(2000, 1, 3)]
# or
df.query("index == @datetime.date(2000, 1, 3)")
```

If you need to select a range of dates between dates, `query` is very convenient (or `between` works too):

```py
date1 = datetime.date(2000, 1, 3)
date2 = datetime.date(2000, 1, 5)

df.query("@date1 <= index <= @date2")
# or
df[df.index.to_series().between(date1, date2)]
```